# How to include an argument in a JSON expression: "Problems parsing JSON"

Tags: json, bash, git-bash

I would like to have a script `git-repository` that create a github repository, taking one argument

```
# git-repository <my_repository_name>
```

I am however unable to include a $@ variable. The expression:

```
curl -u mygituser https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{"name":"$@"}"
```

gives the error

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create"
}
```

**How to include the $@ variable inside a JSON expression?**

Comment: `"$@"` is a *list*. It can't be safely expanded into a single string at all (if there's more than one argument in the list, you get your single string split into multiple ones).

Comment: ...to demonstrate that more clearly: `set -- "first argument" "second argument"`; `printf '%s\n' "our string is <$@>"` will print `our string is <first argument` as one line (as that is the first argument passed to `printf` after its format string), and `second argument>` as a second one (being a separate `printf` argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jq` to safely generate JSON in bash. In this case, since you want a *string* rather than an *array*, you should use `$*` rather than `$@`:

```
json=$(jq -nc --arg name "$*" '{"name": $name}')
curl -u mygituser https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "$json"
```